# How to cut a particular piece of data and store it in a String in Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, openssl, aix

I am new at Linux and I am having problems with getting a piece of data from the String. What I tried is

```
str = $(openssh version) | cut -d" " -f2
```

This is what I did the line is not showing any error but the string is containing null. When I am running this in console I am getting the required output

```
echo $(openssh version) | cut -d" " -f2
```

this gives output `1.0.0c`(openssl version number)this is what I require when I run it in shell script as I want to compare it with other string.

Did I made any mistake in syntax or if there is some other way to do it.
Should run both in Linux and AIX system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your "cut" command inside the parens, and eliminate the whitespace around "=":

```
str=$(openssh version | cut -d" " -f2)
```